# HP laptop uefi bios does not recognize SATA SSD M2

Tags: ssd, bios, uefi, hp

The UEFI BIOS of my HP ProBook G4 has stopped recognizing the SSD unexpectedly. Arch Linux recognizes Grub (which just crashes, though) but if I try to start the system from live USB the drive is not seen by the OS.

What should I do? Is this related to a power outage?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you have a power outage before the issue began?

Comment: I may have had a spike  power from an audio amplifier connected to the DAC usb plugged to laptop

Comment: SSDs can just die with no warning whatsoever. Statistically, for large populations, the studies say they are more reliable, but I've never had a decent HDD less than a year old just die overnight before.

Comment: the ssd isn't broken since it is seen on another machine

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities :

1. Your SSD has just died
2. The power spike caused hardware damage.

Try another SSD to see if it's seen by the BIOS/UEFI
(it won't be candidate in the boot order if it doesn't have a bootable OS).

If the new SSD is seen by a bootable USB, then the old SSD is dead and
should be replaced, hoping that you have backups for your data.

If the new SSD is also not recognized, then you need to have the computer
repaired. There is in that case a damage to some hardware component
that a repair-shop will be better equipped to analyze.